# how to pass dropdownlist selected value to get function in controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am totally new to asp.net MVC,I have a dropdownlist  filled from database. Now I need to send the selected value(id) in get function in controller so i can load the selected value details 
Here is the code which I have tried.

**View:**

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductName, new SelectList(Model.ProductsList, "ProductID", "ProductName"),  new
                   {
                       id = "Productslist",
                       @class = "GreenDropDownListStyle",
                       @datastyle = "dropdown",
                   })
```

**java Script code:**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Productslist").change(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var SelectedProductID = this.value;
                    if (SelectedProductID != "") {
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: '/Inventory/ViewProduct',
                                data: { ProductID: SelectedProductID },
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                success: function (details) {
                                    //alert("success"); 
                                },

                            });
                    } else {
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
```

this code can get the id of selected and view succeed alert message but it doesn't send the selected value (id) to the post function in controller

**Cotroller :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewProduct(int? ProductID)
    {
         if (ProductID != null && ProductID >0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
               message = "";
            }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Delete the `contentType` option (you are not stringifying the data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var jsn = { ProductID: SelectedProductID };
            jsn = JSON.stringify(jsn);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Inventory/ViewProduct",
                data: jsn,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function () {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `POST` as the http method here.

```
$.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/Inventory/ViewProduct',
   data: { ProductID: SelectedProductID },
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (details) {
      //alert("success"); 
   }
});
```

Worth checking out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details on how to use jquery ajax function.

By the way, use `type: 'POST'` instead of `method: 'POST'` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.